# Need help understanding IDA Pro pseudocode

Tags: ida, decompilation

I am new into IDA and have some questions about the pseudocode in C.
Could someone please explain to me the meaning of the following two lines:

- `(*(void (__fastcall **)(int *, _DWORD))(*v1 + 196))(v1, *(_DWORD *)(*v1 + 200));`

What does `(*v1 + 196)` mean?

- `if ( *(_BYTE *)(dword_9AEC7FB0 + 170) & 1 && !*(_DWORD *)(dword_9AEC7FB0 + 92) )`

What is `dword_9AEC7FB0`? A global variable?

Comment: Duplicate. Question 1: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9509/what-is-the-meaning-of-dword/9510     Question 2: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18946/whats-the-meaning-of-dword-xxxx-and-offset-dword-xxxx-in-ida